# How to remove the duplicate value in the store extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to remove the duplicate value in this store.

Sometimes, the url return some duplicate value, how can I remove the duplicate value and just list that value 1 time?

```
var input1store = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields: [{name: 'name'}],
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source1',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'xml.result'
        }
    },
    autoLoad:false,
    sorters: [{property: 'name', direction: 'asc'}]
});
```

Code that I have base on your suggestion, but still not working.  Input1store2 should contain the unique value only.

```
var input1storeArray = [];
var input1store = new Ext.data.Store({
fields: [{name: 'name'}],
proxy:{
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source1',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'xml.result'
    }
},
autoLoad:false,
sorters: [{property: 'name', direction: 'asc'}],
listeners: {
  load: function(store){
input1storeArray = Ext.Array.unique(store.getRange());
}
  }
});


var input1store2 = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
field = ['name'],
data =  input1storeArray 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything built-in. You would need either to enforce it on the model level - making this field unique and handling the errors, or load the store, sort by that field and go through all records comparing last one and next one.

Comment: I have tried to do base on what you suggest here. But I fail to make it work. Is that possible that you give me an example or a quick code for this. THanks

Comment: Can you post your code and I will try to help you find an error?

Comment: I have update the question above include the code to collect the unique value, but it does not seems to work.